# WPF and Caliburn: TreeView with Drap and Drop with context menu

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

I need to develop a TreeView with context menu and drag&drop functionality with Caliburn.Micro. Do you know any tutorials or some sample implementation of it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

More of an extended comment than an answer:

When I was implementing a `TreeView` using Caliburn.Micro (similar to windows explorer navigation), I used this Josh Smith tutorial as a basis: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode

I arrived there from a discussion on the Caliburn Micro Codeplex page: http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/discussions/241503, it's worth searching there for additional hints/tips (e.g. http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/discussions/224729).

For drag & drop, I used the [SharpFellows.Toolkit](http://www.sharpfellows.com/post/WPF-Drag-and-Drop-e28093-doing-it-the-MVVM-way.aspx) at the time, but there are many other libraries available (e.g. [Gong](https://github.com/punker76/gong-wpf-dragdrop), you could even roll your own, depending on your (requirements http://sonyarouje.com/2011/02/16/introduction-to-caliburn-micro-part-2/).